# Integrate File manager [ Codeigniter ]

Tags: php, codeigniter, responsive-filemanager

I am using code codeigniter 3x. I am trying to integrate a file manager - [Responsive FileManager 9.11.3](https://github.com/trippo/ResponsiveFilemanager) .

I tried many time to integrate but everytime getting error.

**Controller file .**

```
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Filemanager extends CI_Controller {

        public function __construct() {
              parent::__construct();
          }


        public function index() {
             $this->load->helper('path');
             $this->load->library('filemanagerx');
             $this->filemanagerx->fmanager();
         }

    }
```

**library file .**

```
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); 
   class Filemanagerx {
        public function fmanager() {
           include_once 'filemanager/dialog.php';
    }
}
```

Comment: In CodeIgniter, since it doesn't support namespacing, you can't have two classes of same name. "I tried many time to integrate but everytime getting error." What is the error?

Comment: `array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given`

Comment: I fixed it using `is_array();` but lot of scripts not working. Iike delete, upload, create new folder etc.

Comment: Too few data provided to be able to understand nature of error. Check here [how to provide question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).